# Joomla Module Install mySQL

Tags: mysql, joomla, installation, manifest, create-table

I am creating a new module, but this time I got an error while creating my database table. Also I am a kind of confused about the file structure for installing this. I have read the Joomla documentation and tried what they're saying:

In my manifest I created the following install/remove (SQL) sections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>Modulename</name>
    <author>Jerry Schirrmann</author>
    <description>A test module</description>
    <files>
        <filename>mod_modulename.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_modulename">mod_modulename.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
        <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
        <filename>sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
        <filename>sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
        <install>
            <sql>
                <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
                <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/install.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </install>

        <uninstall>
            <sql>
                <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
                <file driver="sqlazure" charset="utf8">sql/sqlazure/uninstall.sqlazure.utf8.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </uninstall>
    </config>
</extension>
```

and created the following file structure: 
mod_xxx/sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql **&** mod_xxx/sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql

Now he doesn't give me an error while installing, but just won't create my table.
Is my file structure right? Or is the problem in one of my SQL files?

EDIT: 
*Here is some of MYSQL code*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__modulename` (
        `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `hello` text NOT NULL,
        `lang` varchar(25) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `#__modulename` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Hello World', 'en-GB');
INSERT INTO `#__modulename` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Hola Mundo', 'es-ES');
INSERT INTO `#__modulename` (`hello`, `lang`) VALUES ('Bonjour tout le monde', 'fr-FR');
```

My Joomla is currently on a 3.2, I am developing for 3.1.0.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? Can you provide the code from inside your **.sql** file please. Is the module being installed even though the database table isn't being created?

Comment: My Joomla is currently on a 3.2, i am developing for 3.1.0. See EDIT for SQL

Comment: Have you included `<folder>sql</folder>` inside the `<files>` tags?

Comment: Updated manifest section

Comment: you have not defined module version may be you miss script file for install module

Comment: @RakeshSharma: line 2 >> `version="3.1.0"`

Comment: @Lodder module version not joomla version?

Comment: @RakeshSharma ahh fair enough. even though it's good to include the module version, it's not a requirement. It won't prevent from the SQL running. I believe it's because the sql code is incomplete. As mentioned in my answer, the OP forgot to add the `id` when inserting the values

Comment: Okay so i added the folder SQL into my manifest. Changed the insert to 1 line insert. But still it won't create my table. In my module inside joomla it add's the following file structure: modules/mod_helloworld/sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql, i am just wondering if this is the place to be

Comment: did you copy and paste my code exactly? If you have extra code for you SQL file, leave that for the time being. Copy my code exactly and see if it works

Comment: I got it, might be a stupid mistake... but my folder structure was as follows: modules/mod_helloworld/sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql
Deleted the mysql folder, and reinstalled the component.

Comment: I would like to thank both of you for helping, as i sayed in the beginnen. I was a bit confused about the file structure.. Youre info helped me alot

Comment: i don't get it jerry, what was the problem finally? i have the same problem

Comment: it looks odd that your install and uninstall blocks are in the config block

Comment: I don't get it, the mysql folder must be there according to your configuration

Comment: @jerry is there any chance you can e-mail me upload your working hello world module somehwere? this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XML file further down, you should have something similar to this:

```
<files>
    <filename module="mod_modulename">mod_modulename.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
</files>
```

Make sure you also include `<folder>sql</folder>`.

As for you SQL code, try the following which is only using 1 insert command. It also tell it which ID to assign the values to which you forgot in your code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__modulename` (
        `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `hello` text NOT NULL,
        `lang` varchar(25) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `#__modulename` (`id`, `hello`, `lang`) VALUES 
(1, 'Hello World', 'en-GB'),
(2, 'Hola Mundo', 'es-ES'),
(3, 'Bonjour tout le monde', 'fr-FR');
```